# Change textbox value when combox value changes

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a sql database table **login**

```
id 
name(nchar 30)
password(nchar 30)
catagory(nchar 10)
```

and a loginForm which have a `name` ComboBox which stores the names and a `password` TextBox which stores the password and a button `login`. I have retrive values from the table through databinding property of the combobox and textbox. It is showing the values but when I change the combobox value it doesn't show the password related to the combobox value? there are 3 different catagories are stored in the table `student`, `teacher` and `worker` I don't know the way how can I retreive catagory value from the table and open different forms mean when I press the login button the catagory is student student form will open?

how can I solve the password and catagory problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle that in your query..